# How to replace the Secondary menu title with the current Username?

Tags: 7, users, navigation

**Secondary menu** - this is the system secondary menu title.
I need to replace it with current username, the same as the User menu block has it.

I do not want to use the User menu block because of some reasons.
I would like to use the deafault system menu:

```
<?php if ($secondary_menu): ?>
  <div id="secondary-menu" class="navigation">
    <?php print theme('links__system_secondary_menu', array(
      'links' => $secondary_menu,
      'attributes' => array(
        'id' => 'secondary-menu-links',
        'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix'),
      ),
      'heading' => array(
        'text' => t('Secondary menu'),
        'level' => 'h2',
        'class' => array('element-invisible'),
      ),
    )); ?>
  </div> <!-- /#secondary-menu -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Should I use token [current-user:name]?
If so, then where (file name) and how?

**Note**: I can not do it directly at `/admin/structure/menu/manage/user-menu/edit` because Menu name field is inactive.

Comment: So, are you just want instead of `My account` it will show the current login `user-name` in the `default secondary menu`? What drupal version are you using?

Comment: No! I need to replace the  system title - Secondary menu - with username.   I can not do it directly at /admin/structure/menu/manage/user-menu/edit because Menu name field is inactive. Drupal 7. Thank you

Comment: but `Secondary menu` word does not appear in the User interface anywhere as far as I know. Secondary menu show, only `My account` and `Logout` While User Menu Block will show menu-title `User menu` then two list `My account` and `Logout`. These five thing appears to user. out of these which one you wan tot change.

Comment: This is hided by CSS. Look at HTML and you can see it - Secondary menu. I need to replace it with username.

Comment: /**
 * Override or insert variables into the block template.
 */
function bartik_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  // In the header region visually hide block titles.
  if ($variables['block']->region == 'header') {
    $variables['title_attributes_array']['class'][] = 'element-invisible';
  }
}

Comment: Pls look initial post. 'text' => t('Secondary menu') - I need current username instead of 'Secondary menu' here.

Comment: please have look at updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can simply do this by making change in `page.tpl.php` file.

Just replace,

```
'text' => t('Secondary menu'),
```

with,

```
'text' => t($user->name),
```

save and clear cache.

**Image-1:** Before changing code *(I have deleted line `'class' => array('element-invisible'),` so text can be visible)*

[image]

**Image-2:** After change,

[image]

Final code,

```
<?php if ($secondary_menu): ?>
      <div id="secondary-menu" class="navigation">
        <?php print theme('links__system_secondary_menu', array(
          'links' => $secondary_menu,
          'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'secondary-menu-links',
            'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix'),
          ),
          'heading' => array(
            //'text' => t('Secondary menu'),
            'text' => t($user->name),
            'level' => 'h2',
            //'class' => array('element-invisible'),
          ),
        )); ?>
      </div> <!-- /#secondary-menu -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: **CodeNext**, thank you! This is exactly what I need :)

Comment: Yes your answer is very helpful but I do not know how to close it and how to up-vote. Pls advice :)

Comment: I tried to do it but not sure if it was done because I am not registered here on this site. Later I will register (sign up) and will do all the neccessary things.