# How to override theme() part in page.tpl.php file?

Tags: 7, theming, hooks

This question is extension of this question: [Current Username title instead Secondary menu title](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/216734/current-username-title-instead-secondary-menu-title), but it is different.

I would like to how can I override the following part of code  `theme('links__system_secondary_menu',............)` which is in `page.tpl.php`

For example, if I want to change `text => t('Secondary menu')` to `text => t('Any new text')`.

*One way to do this, which I think is just change that part in `page.tpl.php` and it works perfectly.*

### OR

*Is there any other way like hook-way to do this, so we can write function in `template.php` and that override only that part?*

*from page.tpl.php*

```
<?php if ($secondary_menu): ?>
      <div id="secondary-menu" class="navigation">
        <?php print theme('links__system_secondary_menu', array(
          'links' => $secondary_menu,
          'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'secondary-menu-links',
            'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix'),
          ),
          'heading' => array(
            'text' => t('Secondary menu'),
            'level' => 'h2',
            'class' => array('element-invisible'),
          ),
        )); ?>
      </div> <!-- /#secondary-menu -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override theme_links__system_secondary_menu() in template.php. You will name it MODULENAME_links__system_secondary_menu(), and the original code can be seen here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_links/7.x

Copy that code, and modify it as necessary.

Comment: Its perfect....